# How does the Divine Blessing of Triune work?

Tags: feats, starfinder, hacking

The description of the [Divine Blessing](https://aonsrd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Divine%20Blessing) of Triune says:

> *Triune*: You can use a computer without having a user interface or hacking kit simply by touching it. You must still succeed at a Computers check to hack it if you do not have authorized access. Additionally, you have limited telepathy that functions only with constructs with the technological subtype.

Limited Wifi-Telepathy is great, and you still have to make a skill check to hack. However, what if you need to download or upload information and your only contact with it is touch? Can you store digital data within yourself, since the source of the ability is supernatural?

When it says "use a computer without having a user interface or hacking kit simply by touching", would "use" in this case cover the transfer and of deliverance of data? How much data can user hold?

I'd like to know the limitations of this feat.

Answer (score 2):

### Abilities do what they say, not everything you could think it might.

The benefits are listed

- use a computer without user interface
- hack a computer without a hacking kit (with a successful Computers check)
- telepathy to construct (technological)

It doesn't say anything about storing digital data, so you cannot do that. You could insert a removable storage and interface to download data to that, but you are not yourself a data storage device. That being said, you do *remember* the data you've browsed; you just don't have an actual digital copy (say, if you needed to provide evidence of the mayor's corruption to the local constabulary).

### Of course, ask your GM

This sounds like a super interesting way to use the ability that doesn't add a ton of intrinsic value to the ability. Ask your GM if they'll handwave it for your setting (although beware the dread antimagic field, which would probably (?) mind-wipe any information you made off with).